# Who monitors mailbox of each Actors?

Tags: scala, akka

I know actors are persistent, They are always alive sitting idle as long as there is nothing to do(no messages in the mailbox), So who monitors the mailbox ?

Is it the Actor itself ? but it doesn't have a thread assigned from dispatcher until its having a message.?

Or, is there any background daemon running monitoring mailboxes of each actors?

Comment: Actors are not persitent. But you can add persistence to Actors. And Actors do not sit idle (as they are not actual working parts). Its just that they are not shceduled with a Thread. And the mailboxes are owned by the dispatcher.

Comment: So dispatchers are monitoring the actor mailboxes ??

Comment: Actually mailbox being owned by dispatcher is largely inaccurate. But what do you mean by "monitoring" here ?

Comment: monitoring means ? "Any new mails for Me" ?? i.e. Any new messages for any particular Actor .?

Comment: Actors are persistent according to this https://youtu.be/lPTqcecwkJg?t=198

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh : Thanks for clarifying the Akka persistence.

Answer (score 2):

As @Sarvesh Kumar Singh mentioned, actor is not by default persistent. You can create persistent actor by extending PersistentActor: [Akka Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/persistence.html).
In fact, when a actor(cell) is created in the actor system hierarchy, its mailbox([Mailbox](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch/Mailbox.scala) is a subclass of Runnable) will be attached to the dispatcher, when the actor is started, the dispatcher will then execute the mailbox runnable(defined in the run method) by polling message from the mailbox queue, if there's a message, it will trigger the defined actor receive method to actually handle the message. Message looping(during this run, the messages in the queue will the be handled into batch, if handling this batch of batch doesn't pass the limit of dispatcher throughput configuration) is also done in the run method by a recursive call of processMailBox defined in mailbox. At the end of each round, the mail box will attach itself to the dispatcher thread pool for execution if there's messages the actor mail box is scheduled for execution the the loop continues. If not, the loop is broken, the next run will be scheduled when there's message sent to the actor, at this moment, message will be dispatched via the dispatcher attached with the actor cell when you call actorRef ! message, this will make the dispatcher to schedule the message handling, check this out: [Dispatch::sendMessage](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/dungeon/Dispatch.scala) and [Dispatcher::dispatch](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch/Dispatcher.scala). As explained in [Dispatchers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html.), dispatcher's throughput can be configured to determine the maximum number of messages to be processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.

Comment: Ok, Now suppose there are no message and there are 1000 actors. So Dispatchers are just busy polling the 1000 mailboxes. ? is it ?

Comment: No, since when there's no message in the actor, a actor run method will not be scheduled again. No runnable will be queued into the dispatcher thread pool. The next message comes to a actor will be dispatched via the dispatcher attached with this actor cell, and at this moment the dispatcher will schedule the execution of the message handling of the actor. I will edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: So actually, the dispatcher is not "monitoring" the mailbox, in the implementation of Akka actor,  it's actually the backend entry point when you send the message to a actor.

Comment: So no message, no scheduling, no overhead.

Comment: Yes, if there's no message, the dispatcher will not schedule the mail processMessage loop.